# how to mask out "USE INDEX" in MySQL query running on h2

Tags: java, mysql, h2

I am testing a MySQL query using local h2 for a java application. The problem is that h2 does not support "USE INDEX" (index hint) in the MySQL query. It reports "Syntax error in SQL statement". Is there a way to run this query with the USE INDEX masked out in h2?

I tried to use an alias to replace USE INDEX part with an empty string:

```
CREATE ALIAS `USE INDEX` FOR "<java-function-that-returns-empty-string>"
```

but it did not work, i.e. still reports "Syntax error in SQL statement".  I suspect it's because 'USE INDEX' is two words, not supported by alias? but I am not sure. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using queries written for mysql in h2?

Comment: our production env. is in mysql, but the unit testing is using h2. I have no control over the database engine for unit testing, nor the production env. Btw we use a 'migrations.sql' in unit testing to setup the h2.  That is where I was trying "CREATE ALIAS".

Comment: The way ORM tools usually solve this problem is with different *dialects* for each target database.

Comment: thanks @ElliottFrisch. Our code base is not using ORM though. Finally I decided to subclass the data access interface and override the query with 'USE INDEX' removed. The subclass is only for unit testing. Now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 3):

H2 doesn't currently support the non-standard MySQL "USE INDEX" syntax. So your SQL is invalid for H2.

However I'm currently adding this to H2.

Comment: thank you for your work on h2. Please do not forget FORCE INDEX as well as USE INDEX. =) personally all I need is for the syntax to be considered legal so my test suite will pass.

Comment: great ! Is there a pull request opened ? Can we take a look ?

Comment: Look like he forgot, about FORCE INDEX, it doesn't work (bad SQL grammar) which is kinda problematic when you want to use H2 for automatic tests of code written for MySQL :(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, finally, I had found a simple and elegant solution:

```
select 
count(*)  from category t /*! use index(primary) */
```

This kind of comment is interpreted only by MySQL, but not by H2 so that's it.